# Run Python program from shell and keep variables in scope

Tags: python, interactive

Python has a nice `execfile` function inside the interpreter where you can run a program, keep all the variables in scope, and then inspect them at your leisure. However, as far as I know you can't run `execfile` on a program that takes arguments from the command line; if you try to include the arguments, Python throws an `IOError` and complains that the file (with spaces and arguments) can't be found.

Is there any way to run a Python script that takes command line arguments, and keep all of the variables in scope after the program executes? Like an `execfile` that takes flags?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: This sounds all sorts of messed up.

Comment: why not use like `run blah.py -i 0 -m 1` in ipython

Comment: You should avoid using execfile whenever possible. It has it's uses, but I don't think this use case is one of them.

Comment: Ignacio, could you explain why? I just realized I guess I could run pdb and put a breakpoint right at the end of program execution, then inspect things when the program stops. I just like being able to inspect all the variables without having to change one thing and re-run the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could modify `sys.argv` directly. The file:

```
# foo.py
import sys

print sys.argv
```

The other file:

```
import sys
import shlex   # thanks Matt

old_argv = sys.argv
sys.argv = shlex.split('foo.py is a happy camper')

execfile('foo.py')
```

Output:

```
$ python foo.py is a happy camper
['foo.py', 'is', 'a', 'happy', 'camper']
$ python bar.py 
['foo.py', 'is', 'a', 'happy', 'camper']
```

But I must say, quoting Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams:

> This sounds all sorts of messed up.

I'm assuming you have your reasons though.

Comment: I wouldn't do this either. But if I did, I'd use the shlex module to build my new `sys.argv`.